# Debugging RuntimeError: workspace already in transaction mode from arcpy.da.UpdateCursor and ArcSDE feature classes?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, arcgis-10.1, enterprise-geodatabase, cursor

I am making my first attempt at editing an ArcSDE feature class with python through a da.UpdateCursor. I'm essentially taking code I've written for a file geodatabase feature class and applying it to an SDE feature class. Doing so produces an error, and I'm not sure how to rectify the problem.

I'm using ArcGIS 10.1 for Desktop.

Pertinent code:

```
Struxfeature = r"DatabaseConnections\PipelinePathways.sde\PPGIS.Strux\PPGIS.StruxPts_v04_all"
P6feature = r"DatabaseConnections\PipelinePathways.sde\PPGIS.Strux\PPGIS.Land_Projects_Parcels_P6"

SDE = r"Database Connections\PipelinePathways.sde"
UserID = "E1B8"
Parent = "SDE.DEFAULT"
version = "change_RW_VC_4447_14_to_C"

#Create Version
print "Creating version"
arcpy.CreateVersion_management(SDE, Parent, version, "PUBLIC")
VersionName = UserID.upper() + "." + version

#Layers
arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management (Struxfeature, "Struxlyr")
arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management (P6feature, "P6lyr")

#Switch to version
print "Switching version"
arcpy.ChangeVersion_management("Struxlyr", "TRANSACTIONAL", VersionName)
arcpy.ChangeVersion_management("P6lyr", "TRANSACTIONAL", VersionName)

#Start editing
print "Initiating editing"
edit = arcpy.da.Editor(SDE)
edit.startEditing()

# Start an edit operation
edit.startOperation()


#Change P6 project numbers   
print "Updating P6.\n"
P6Cursor = arcpy.da.UpdateCursor ("P6lyr", ["P6_NBR", "Name"])
for row in P6Cursor:
    codecodecode
```

The error comes from the line 'for row in P6Cursor:'

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\E1B8\ScriptTesting\ScriptsIUse\ChangeP6.py", line 81, in <module>
    for row in P6Cursor:
RuntimeError: workspace already in transaction mode
```

Comment: You are changing your version to *UserID.upper() + "." + version* but creating a version called *"change_RW_VC_4447_14_to_C"*, is this intentional? I suspect that your problem may arise from *edit.StartEditing*, which has two optional parameters, multiuser_mode defaults to True but may need to be False. Consider using *with* statements for your edit and cursor to help tidy them up when you're finished.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Indeed, to access a created version the format for my VersionName variable is correct. I have read about _with_ statements quite a bit but have not quite started incorporating them into my scripts. I'll work on it. Changing multiuser_mode in edit.StartEditing to False did not change the resulting error.

Comment: What underlying database are you using? If you are using PostgreSQL or other database that allows multiple databases perhaps create a test database and try it without the versioning / without the startEditing-startOperation... take the code back to simplest forms until you discover where the problem is occuring. If that isn't an option (you are using Oracle or similar single database) you may need to contact Esri support for a better explanation of what's happening and probable solution.

Comment: It is an Oracle database. If my code is right, I'll talk to the SDE IT folks.

Comment: I think you will find answers to this easier to come by if you can treat this as three separate questions.  For each, I would focus on providing a code snippet that leads to the error message.  I would ask about the one you think is most important or likely to be able to assist you past your blocking point first.

Comment: Someone else is having similar problems http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/120273/using-arcpy-da-editor-on-a-transactional-version-raising-errors . If there's help here consider answering the other post.

Comment: Do you maybe have a hung edit session in existence that is locking the target layer?

Comment: No in this case that connection file points to a version that only I have access to so no one else should be editing on it.

Comment: The question by Emil Brundage linked above was just answered, you may want to have a look at his answer and see if his solution works for your purposes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With help I have found my solution, though the reasoning behind it is a bit blurry currently. In my code, creating a version through one SDE connection file and then creating the feature layer to be edited through another SDE connection file that is connected to the new version works. Also, edit.startEditing must have the variable 'multiuser_mode' set to true (the default). As I understand it, this variable indicates whether there can be multiple versions/users allowed for the layer. Since this is always true for an SDE feature layer, setting this variable to False causes an error.

Functioning code, where I test an update cursor:

```
import arcpy
import os
#Locals
P6featureName = r"PPGIS.Strux\PPGIS.Land_Projects_Parcels_P6"
Parent = "SDE.DEFAULT"
version = "SDE_Test"
Server = ***
Service = ***
user = ***
Pass = ***
SDE = "Database Connections\PipelinePathways.sde"
temploc = r"C:\E1B8\ScriptTesting\Workspace"
fil = "SDETempConn"

env.overwriteOutput = True

#Create Version
print "Creating version"
arcpy.CreateVersion_management (SDE, Parent, version, "PUBLIC")
VersionName = user.upper() + "." + version

#Create new connection
workspace = os.path.join (temploc, fil + ".sde")
print "Creating SDE connection"
arcpy.CreateArcSDEConnectionFile_management (temploc, fil, Server, Service, username = user, password = Pass, version = VersionName)

#Layers
P6feature = os.path.join (workspace, P6featureName)
arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management (P6feature, "P6lyr")

#Start editing
print "Initiating editing"
edit = arcpy.da.Editor (workspace)
edit.startEditing ()
edit.startOperation()

#Test Cursor
print "Testing cursor"
P6Cursor = arcpy.da.UpdateCursor ("P6lyr", ["NAME"])
for row in P6Cursor:
    print row[0]
del row
del P6Cursor

#Stop/save edits
edit.stopOperation()
print "Stopping editing"
edit.stopEditing("True")

#Switch to version
print "Switching version"
arcpy.ChangeVersion_management("P6lyr", "TRANSACTIONAL", Parent)

#Reconcile and post
print "Reconciling and posting"
arcpy.ReconcileVersions_management (workspace, "", Parent, VersionName, with_post = "POST", with_delete = "DELETE_VERSION")
```

Thanks to Ben Nadler for the help.

Comment: Edited to include starting and stopping operation. Thanks to this post for the info: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/80058/how-to-edit-postgresql-geodatabase-table-using-arcpy

Answer (score 3):

In my case the table we were inserting into was not registered with the geodatabase and was never going to be registered. Adding a primary key and identity column resolved this issue for us.

Answer (score 1):

I've run into the same problem: "workspace already in transaction mode".
I had Microsoft SQL Server database connected to ArcCatalog as SDE.

And decision in my case was just to change type of column "timestamp" of target table to "image".

Answer (score 1):

I also had that  error  in my  python script  while adding  new Feature layers.
After wasting a lot of time I figured that the layers were not registered.
 So  I registered  the  layers  and  got it  working  .