# Using arcpy.da.editor on a transactional version raising errors

Tags: arcpy, sql-server, editing, versioning

I've run up against a wall trying to get an edit session to work on a version. These are the scenarios Ive gone through in the code and their error mesages:

Setting up an edit session not as a context manager: 'workspace already in transaction mode'

```
target = r'D:\GIS-DATA\bay-arcgis-pro_ParcelEditing.sde\sde.SDE.Staging\sde.SDE.SPRCodeEnforcementCasesStaging'
try:
    edit =  arcpy.da.Editor(r'D:\GIS-DATA\bay-arcgis-pro_ParcelEditing.sde')
    edit.startEditing(False,False)
    edit.startOperation()
    with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(target,'*') as cursor:
        for row in cursor:
            row[3] = 'test'
            cursor.updateRow(row)
finally:
    edit.stopOperation()
    edit.stopEditing(True)

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "D:\GIS-DATA\editortest.py", line 9, in <module>
for row in cursor:
RuntimeError: workspace already in transaction mode
```

Setting up an edit session as a context manager: 'The requested operation is invalid on a closed state'

```
target = r'D:\GIS-DATA\bay-arcgis-pro_ParcelEditing.sde\sde.SDE.Staging\sde.SDE.SPRCodeEnforcementCasesStaging'
with arcpy.da.Editor(r'D:\GIS-DATA\bay-arcgis-pro_ParcelEditing.sde'):
    with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(target,'*') as cursor:
        for row in cursor:
            row[3] = 'test'
            cursor.updateRow(row)

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "D:\GIS-DATA\editortest.py", line 8, in <module>
cursor.updateRow(row)
RuntimeError: The requested operation is invalid on a closed state
```

The data is versioned on a SQLServer geodatabase.

Comment: I saw that error message on http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/119938/error-with-da-updatecursor-and-sde-feature-classes#comment170912_119938 - I'm not sure what's going on here so I recommend talking to Esri support and if you get an answer you can help Emil Brundage with his problem also; his error message is on an Oracle database.