# ReconcileVersions tool yields ERROR 000301

Tags: arcpy, reconcile

I am wanting to create a version, step into the version, make edits, and then post and reconcile that version.  When I get to the ReconcileVersions_management tool, it is giving me

`ERROR 000301: The workspace is of the wrong type`

I think that might mean "the version is locked for editing" or "the connection to the db is still open--we can't operate on it".  I'm posting my long-ish code, looking for answers.

```
import arcpy
import os
from datetime import datetime

# make a connection to SDE.DEFAULT
try:
    filename1 = "fn1"
    foldername1 = os.path.join(os.environ['APPDATA'],"ESRI","Desktop10.2","ArcCatalog")
    servername1 = "gissvc"
    servicename1 = "sde:oracle11g:GISDEVR"
    dbname1 = ""
    auth1 = ""
    un1 = "MyUser"
    pass1 = "MyPass"
    userinfo1 = ""
    ver1 = "SDE.DEFAULT"
    sv1 = "SAVE_VERSION"

    if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(os.environ['APPDATA'],"ESRI","Desktop10.2","ArcCatalog", filename1 + ".sde")):
        os.remove(os.path.join(os.environ['APPDATA'],"ESRI","Desktop10.2","ArcCatalog", filename1 + ".sde"))
    print "creating connection to " + ver1    
    arcpy.CreateArcSDEConnectionFile_management(foldername1, filename1, servername1,
                                                    servicename1, dbname1, auth1,
                                                    un1, pass1,  userinfo1, ver1, sv1)
    ws1 = os.path.join(os.environ['APPDATA'],"ESRI","Desktop10.2","ArcCatalog", filename1 + ".sde")
    ver2 = "net_edits"

# create a version

    for version in arcpy.da.ListVersions(ws1):
        if ver2 in version.name:
            print ver2 + " exists, deleting"
            arcpy.DeleteVersion_management(ws1, version.name)  
    print "creating new version, " + ver2
    arcpy.CreateVersion_management(ws1, "SDE.DEFAULT", ver2, "PUBLIC")

# connect to new version

    filename2 = "fn2"
    foldername2 = os.path.join(os.environ['APPDATA'],"ESRI","Desktop10.2","ArcCatalog")
    servername2 = "gissvc"
    servicename2 = "sde:oracle11g:GISDEVR"
    dbname2 = ""
    auth2 = ""
    un2 = "MyUser"
    pass2 = "MyPass"
    userinfo2 = ""
    #ver2 = "net_edits"
    sv2 = "SAVE_VERSION"

    if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(os.environ['APPDATA'],"ESRI","Desktop10.2","ArcCatalog", filename2 + ".sde")):
        os.remove(os.path.join(os.environ['APPDATA'],"ESRI","Desktop10.2","ArcCatalog", filename2 + ".sde"))
    print "creating connection to " + ver2    
    arcpy.CreateArcSDEConnectionFile_management(foldername2, filename2, servername2,
                                                    servicename2, dbname2, auth2,
                                                    un2, pass2,  userinfo2, ver2, sv2)
    ws2 = os.path.join(os.environ['APPDATA'],"ESRI","Desktop10.2","ArcCatalog", filename2 + ".sde")

# edit some things -- select where status = 5, change to "tacos"

    tbl_vw = "t"
    where = 'STATUS = 5'
    arcpy.MakeTableView_management(os.path.join(ws2, "fooditems"), tbl_vw, where, "", "")
    arcpy.CalculateField_management(tbl_vw, "STATUS", '"tacos"')

# close connections

    arcpy.ClearWorkspaceCache_management()
    print arcpy.GetMessages()

# reconcile with post

    reclogname = "reconcile_log_" + str(datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')) + ".txt"
    reclog = os.path.join("F:\PythonScripts","ErrorLogFiles",reclogname)
    if os.path.isfile(reclog):
        os.remove(reclog)
    print "reconciling with post and delete_version options set"
    arcpy.ReconcileVersions_management(ws2, "ALL_VERSIONS", "SDE.Default", ver2,
                                   "LOCK_ACQUIRED", "ABORT_CONFLICTS", "BY_OBJECT",
                                   "FAVOR_TARGET_VERSION", "POST", "DELETE_VERSION", reclog)
except Exception as e:
    print e.message
```

Comment: I'm not sure if it will help you, but I stumbled my way through SDE code until I figured it out here: http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/123422/35230

Answer (score 1):

I had this same issue-- spent time troubleshooting the operation in ArcMap (where it was successful), then copying the python snippet from the Results pane and comparing to my code.

End result: when referring to the default version in arcpy.ReconcileVersions_management, it must be sde.DEFAULT, not SDE.Default. I had this as well, took me a long time to figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this error by changing the connection type to 'dbo.DEFAULT'.  This was successful because my connection file was made with a user with a dbo role in SQL (even though the sde connection authentication is OS).

[How To: Automate reconcile, post and compress processes](http://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000011679)

[DBO or SDE or what Schema?](https://geonet.esri.com/thread/90910)