# Runtime Error: Cannot Open Feature Class in Editor Session

Tags: arcpy, cursor

I am using an update cursor in a script and need to make edits from arcpy.da.Editor.  The error that is being thrown is a Runtime Error where the feature class cannot be opened.

```
import arcpy
import GetSRConfig
import os

def GetThisDir():
    import inspect
    return os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(inspect.getfile(inspect.currentframe())))


sDir = GetThisDir()
sSDECon = os.path.join(sDir, GetSRConfig.SDEConnFile)
sdeLayer = os.path.join(sSDECon, GetSRConfig.LN_SDEDATA)
pWorksapce = (sSDECon)


edit = arcpy.da.Editor(pWorksapce)

edit.startEditing(False, False)

srField = "NUMBERCYLA"
vehNameDi = dict ([(sr, vehNam) for sr, vehName
                in arcpy.da.SearchCursor
                (GetSRConfig.LN_SDEDATA, [GetSRConfig.FN_NUMBERCYLA, GetSRConfig.FN_VehiclNam],"""VehicleNam <> ''""")])

with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(GetSRConfig.LN_SDEDATA, [GetSRConfig.FN_NUMBERCYLA,GetSRConfig.FN_VehiclNam],"""VehicleNam = ''""") as cursor:
    for sr, vehNam in cursor:
        if not sr in vehNameDi:
            continue
        row = (sr, vehNameDi [sr])
        cursor.updateRow (row)

    del cursor
edit.stopEditing(True)
```

Comment: try also startOperation/stopOperation.. all edits to a versioned SDE feature class must be bracketed in an edit operation http://resources.esri.com/help/9.3/arcgisengine/dotnet/30aed52d-4ddc-4daf-b2fb-7dc3ca9a06ec.htm#VersionedEditing (this is arcobjects but sort of explains the behavior).

Comment: I struggled with editing an SDE and came up with this solution, though I'm not sure how specific to my case it was http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/119938/error-with-da-updatecursor-and-sde-feature-classes/123422#123422