# How so I solve FDO error: 0? How do I get code that worked in a file geodatabase to work in an SDE version?

Tags: arcpy, enterprise-geodatabase, python-addin

I used python add in to make a tool bar in Arcmap that edits features on a map. It works on a file geodatabase, but not on an ArcSDE version one. I've been getting an FDO error: 0. The potential solutions that I've found all involve creating an editing session in the script, but so far trying to make those potential solutions work has just lead to more error messages that are starting to seem unrelated to the original issue; I honestly don't think that's the way to go about solving this anymore. Here is the relevant portion of my code:

```
self.x = pythonaddins.GetSelectedTOCLayerOrDataFrame() #Sets FC on different button

fc = str(button2.x)
cursor = arcpy.da.InsertCursor( fc, ["SHAPE@"])
array = arcpy.Array(vertices)
simpleBuilding = arcpy.Polygon(array)
cursor.insertRow([simpleBuilding])
```

all of this code works in a file Geodatabase correctly.
This is the exact error I've been getting when trying to use the tool in a versioned copy:

```
One or more layers failed to draw:
FDO error 0: [Failed to label layer
databaseVersionDBO for class Defaut.}
The requested operation is invalid on a closed state
[database]
```

How do I get this code that works on a file geodatabase to work on an ArcSDE version?
I am new to this.

Edit:

Here is the rest of my code. This still doesn't work, but we have a new error. Here is the error:

```
 in onClick
    edit = arcpy.da.Editor(workspace)
RuntimeError: cannot open workspace
```

Here is the code. I think we're close to resolving this.
here is my code.

```
import arcpy
import pythonaddins
import os
import math
import sys

class setCenterpoint(object):
    """Implementation for leetScripts_addin.tool (Tool)"""
    def __init__(self):
        self.enabled = True
        self.cursor = 3
#selects a point on the map
    def onMouseDownMap(self, x, y, button, shift):
        print "onMouseDowMap executing"
        setCenterpoint.enabled = True 
        self.x = x
        self.y = y       
        print "Selected point is at %r, %r" % (self.x, self.y)
        pass
        return self.x
        return self.y 


class setArea(object):
    """Implementation for leetScripts_addin.combobox (ComboBox)"""
    def __init__(self):
        self.editable = True
        self.enabled = True
        #self.dropdownWidth = ''
        self.width = 'WWWWWWWWW'
#Takes user input Area and returns half the side length of the square
    def onEditChange(self,text) :
        squareFeet = text 
        self.buffDist = (math.sqrt(float(squareFeet))/2)
        print "Square size: %r ft^2 Buffer Distance: %r ft^2" % (squareFeet,
                                                                 self.buffDist)
        return self.buffDist
        pass

#This is supposed to be how you select the feature class, but right now
#it doesn't do anything for debugging purposes.
class SeltLayer(object):
    """Implementation for leetScripts_addin.button2 (Button)"""
    def __init__(self):
        self.enabled = True
        self.checked = False
    def onClick(self):
        #need the input as a string not a class layer.
        self.x = pythonaddins.GetSelectedTOCLayerOrDataFrame()
        print "Selected filepath is: %r" % self.x.dataSource
        print "filepath is %r type" % type(self.x.dataSource)
        pass


class buildingTool(object):
    """Implementation for leetScripts_addin.button (Button)"""
    def __init__(self):
        self.enabled = True
        self.checked = False
    def onClick(self):
        print "building tool button is executing"
#Variables for Creating the polygon
        xCoordinate = float(tool.x)
        yCoordinate = float(tool.y)
        bob = float(combobox.buffDist)
        #fc = str(button2.x.dataSource) was used to get featureclass info
        fc = r"realfulldatabasepath\realnextpart\realpolygonlayer"

        outFolderPath = r"U:\tempStuff"
        outName = r"actualName"
        databasePlatform = "SQL_Server"
        instance = "realinstance"
        username = "myusername"
        password = "authenticpassword"
        version = "myVersionName"
        arcpy.CreateDatabaseConnection_management(outFolderPath, outName,
                                                  databasePlatform,
                                                  instance,
                                                  'DATABASE_AUTH',
                                                  username, password,
                                                  'DO_NOT_SAVE_USERNAME',
                                                  'databasename',
                                                  '','TRANSACTIONAL',
                                                  version,)
        print "Centroid of buidling:(%r,%r) Side length: %r" % (xCoordinate,
                                                                yCoordinate,
                                                                bob)
        def doStuff():
            #Calculates and creates an array of vertex points, opens an
            #insert cursor, creates a polygon using the arra, and inserts
            #building into the appropriate database. This works fine in file
            #geodatabase
            vertices = []
            vertices.append(arcpy.Point((xCoordinate + bob), (yCoordinate + bob)))
            vertices.append(arcpy.Point((xCoordinate + bob), (yCoordinate - bob)))
            vertices.append(arcpy.Point((xCoordinate - bob), (yCoordinate - bob)))
            vertices.append(arcpy.Point((xCoordinate - bob), (yCoordinate + bob)))
            vertices.append(arcpy.Point((xCoordinate + bob), (yCoordinate + bob)))

            cursor = arcpy.da.InsertCursor( fc, ["SHAPE@"])
            array = arcpy.Array(vertices)
            simpleBuilding = arcpy.Polygon(array)
            cursor.insertRow([simpleBuilding])


            del cursor
            print "Building should be drawn"

        desc = arcpy.Describe(fc)
        print "%r" % desc
        sde = desc.catalogPath.find('.sde')

#Checks for .sde versions code provided by BenSNadler.
        #arcpy.Describe().isVersioned needs dataset input
        if sde != -1 and desc.isVersioned:
            workspace = desc.catalogPath#problem opening workspace
            print workspace
            #Start editing
            print "initiating editing"
            edit = arcpy.da.Editor(workspace)
            edit.startEditing(True, True)
            edit.startOperation()

            #soon to be function's name
            doStuff()
            print "made it past function call."

            #Stop/save edits
            edit.stopOperation()
            print "Stopping editing"
            edit.stopEditing(True)
        #if no versions then the function runs without using the
        #connection    
        else:
            print "made it to else statemenet"
            doStuff()
            print "made it past function call"
```

Comment: Welcome to the Enterpise Geodatabase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Debugging RuntimeError: workspace already in transaction mode from arcpy.da.UpdateCursor and ArcSDE feature classes?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/119938) has working code on how to do this.

The errors you may be dealing with involve whether or not the data is versioned and if you have edit permissions

As per [Editing PostgreSQL geodatabase table using ArcPy?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/80058), if the tables are versioned with the option to move the edits to the base, THEN you do not use startOperation() and stopOperation(). HOWEVER, if your tables are versioned in the default manner, then you need to control transaction operations explicitly. I can't say I fully understand why this makes a difference, but in my case it was absolutely the solution.

If you don't know what the data source might be, I recommend you check the type of workspace. that way it would work on SDE or file gdb. Do something like this:

```
desc = arcpy.Describe(fc)
sde = desc.catalogPath.find('.sde') #if SDE this will return a value
#If in sde AND is Versioned, use editor start/stop
if sde != -1 and desc.isVersioned:
    #get the connection information
    workspace = os.path.split (desc.catalogPath)[0]
    #Start editing
    print "Initiating editing"
    edit = arcpy.da.Editor (workspace)
    edit.startEditing ()
    edit.startOperation()

    DO STUFF

    #Stop/save edits
    edit.stopOperation()
    print "Stopping editing"
    edit.stopEditing("True")
     `
```

Comment: The arcpy.Editor also does not fully interface with the interactive Editor of ArcMap.  If your code does not explicitly save edits then the user has to save edits through the interactive Editor to keep them, but at the same time you cannot undo operations through the undo/redo buttons and can only discard edits by not saving them.  Since my tool lets the user choose any data source, Python does not provide the means to tell what the user really started editing.  It is enough of an issue for me that I am going to start over with an ArcObjects addin tool.  Esri support had no better solution.

Comment: Bottomline for me is that arcpy cannot be used to build a tool that is functionally equivalent to any of the interactive editing tools provided by Esri.  Only ArcObjects gives the required information and control needed to do that.

Comment: @RichardFairhurst I've read about ArcObjects, but I didn't realize that it was entirely separate from arcpy. I ran into this problem the first time I tried to write this code. I was trying to get values from tables. Turns out you can't do math with values from tables because they don't have a type. I'll like into this. Can you recommend any starting points for ArcObjects?

Comment: It is probably best to start here http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcobjects/latest/net/webframe.htm  The learning curve is pretty steep and you have to handle a lot more steps to get ArcObjects to do anything similar to arcpy.  Geonet has a lot of converted forum posts that deal with the VBA form of ArcObjects, and most of the coding principals remain the same.  Not sure what tables you were trying to work with in arcpy, but if these were dba or gdb tables they are accessible through ListTables like Layers are thru ListLayers.  Excel isn't worth using given the trouble it causes, in my opinion.

Comment: As mentioned, arcObjects is a lot harder to write than python. Unless you encounter a functional limitation I suggest you try python first.

Comment: @BenSNadler I don't understand your answer. Are you saying that I need to make a connection to do this? I've tried this code both with and without startOperation() stopOperation(). They both fail and return the same error.

Comment: You need to initialize the editor, which you do by passing it a workspace path.    Per the first link there are some parameters that need to be set with startOperation() in versioned dbs.  See the help http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/arcpy-data-access/editor.htm

Comment: @BenSNadler I've tried doing that in the past and I've run into an issue with not being able to open the workspace. How do I figure out which workspace I need to open? Is this error a permissions issue?

Comment: If you lacked privileges you would get a different error. IS YOUR DATA VERSIONED With the option to move to base? Check the properties of the data you are trying to edit

Comment: @BenSNadler I've been told that the data does not have this option. I'm trying to figure out how to check that now. I don't understand what creating a connection does or what I need the connection to do. Are my outputs the database I'm trying to edit?

Comment: I am guessing you are looking at the sample. That creates a connection because it is also creating a named version which did not exist before the code ran, therefore it needs a new connection file. This is not necessary if you have a connection file already pointing to the version you want to edit. In my code the connection file is pulled from the input feature class path. You need the connection to initialize the editor

Comment: @BenSNadler I still can't open the workspace. Is that an indicator that I need to create a connection file? The only information I was able to find regarding my connection was that I had a direct connection to the geodatabase.

Comment: Are you unable to edit the data in ArcMap through the connection? Do you first have to create a version in ArcMap before editing? Is the default version protected? If any of these are "Yes" then you have a permissions issue.

Comment: @BenSNadler The default version is locked. Does this mean that it's protected and that I have a permissions issue? I'm using arcpy.CreateDatabaseConnection_management to create my connection. Is the out_folder_path the folder path that the geodatabase I'm trying to connect to is in? Is the out_name the name of the geodatabase I'm trying to connect to? I'm struggling with the connections concept.

Comment: Yes, the locked default version means you cannot start an edit session in it. Python requires you provide a valid workspace to edit in. The connection file contains the workspace definition. In your case, due to lack of privilege  you will need the connection file to point to some version that you can edit. Look at the previoisly referenced post for an implementation of this and do your due diligence and  read the help on the tool. It clearly describes the parameters. http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/create-arcsde-connection-file.htm.

Comment: @BenSNadler I wouldn't have expected that since I can edit the layer in question in my version in arcmaps without a permissions issue. I've read the documentation many times over many days. Are those two variables whatever I decide to make them?

Comment: Yup, whatever you want. Your connection file needs to point to your version. This can be done programmatically when creating a nre connection file or if your version is static configure a connection file to point to it and just pass it in to the editor.

Comment: @BenSNadler Is there a resource for that you can point me to? I don't understand that at all. Should my workspace be the same as the featureclass?

Comment: http://support.esri.com/sitecore/content/support/Home/other-resources/gis-dictionary/term/workspace, http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.2/index.cfm?TopicName=About_workspaces, http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/geodatabases/an-overview-of-versioning.htm

Comment: @BenSNadler How do I make my connection file point to my version?

Comment: Look at the sample linked  in my original answer, it uses a named version for  the connection file.

Comment: @BenSNadler why create the new versions in that sample link? I'm fairly certain I'm doing everything correctly, but I'm still getting a runtime error preventing me from opening my workspace.

Comment: If you have a named version use it, otherwise create a new one. Can you edit the data in ArcMap? If so, likely there is something wrong with your addin. Perhaps update your question with your code.

Comment: @BenSNadler I made those edits. This doesn't make any sense to me. Everything should be correct. What I have now should be working. I can't find the error.

Comment: I ran your code and it is almost there.  The workspace variable is wrong. If the data you are editing is not in a dataset, then the workspace variable should be the file path of the new connection file. If the data you are trying to edit is in a feature dataset, the workspace variable should be the path to the dataset (NewConnectioFile + Dataset). When you reference the feature class be sure to use the workspace (os.path.join(workspace, FCName)

Comment: @BenSNadler I did what you suggested with the workspace and I'm still getting the runtime error; it looks like the workspace is still wrong. If it isn't the filepath what else could it be?

Comment: Validate your created connection file by opening it in desktop

Comment: @BenSNadler what program do I use to open it? Do you know where the program should be located? How do I open the connection file?

Comment: @BenSNadler The code works now. I think I needed to change the version. The workspace should just be (NewConnectionFile) but the feature class needs to reference the dataset so it should be (os.path.join(workspace, Featuredataset, FCName))

Comment: Thats great news. Please mark the question as answered and have fun with the addin